# Mylyn svn code template message with file id

Tags: eclipse, svn, mylyn

i'm using mylyn with the svn connector and does anybody know how can i set the svn id associated to the file into the comment template field of the mylyn?

To clarify : something similar to [${task.status} - ${connector.task.prefix} ${task.key}: ${task.description} ] in the 'commit comment table' option at preferences.

Is there a command similar to ${task.id}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the commit comment template doesn't have information about the SVN id.  You can see what symbols it does know about by going to Preferences > Mylyn > Team, put your cursor in the Commit Comment Template text box, and type CNTL-space.  This will bring up content assist, which will show you all the legal symbols you can use.